# Crear link a partir de html inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, concatenación

Hola quiero saber si es posible generar un link(`<a href="tel:`) a partir de html inputs. Me explico;

Tengo 3 html text inputs  y esos 3 inputs se deben concatenar para tener como resultado una marcación telefonica. Ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto es que al final el resultado se muestre como un `<a href="tel:` , esto para poder "linkear" el número telefonico.

Comment: Publicá el código de lo que tenés hecho hasta ahora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe crear una función javascript para que en cada evento onChange de los inputs recoja el valor y arme tu href

```
var tel=$('#btn').attr('href')+'tel:'+dato1+dato2+dato3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
(() => {
  class App {
    constructor() {
      this.ObjectDesigner = {};
      this.DataStatic = {
        KeyTitle: "Link",
        KeyPhone: "tel"
      }
    }
    Create() {
      try {
        this.LoadDesigner();
        this.SetDataInDesigner();
        this.ActionGenerateLink();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("index.html/Load =>", error);
      }
    }
    LoadDesigner() {
      try {
        this.ObjectDesigner.InputValue01 = document.getElementById("txtValue01");
        this.ObjectDesigner.InputValue02 = document.getElementById("txtValue02");
        this.ObjectDesigner.InputValue03 = document.getElementById("txtValue03");
        this.ObjectDesigner.ButtonGenerateLink = document.getElementById("btnGenerateLink");
        this.ObjectDesigner.ButtonGenerateLink.addEventListener("click", this.ActionGenerateLink.bind(this), false);
        this.ObjectDesigner.LinkRedirect = document.getElementById("linkRedirect");

      } catch (error) {
        console.log("index.html/LoadDesigner =>", error);
      }
    }
    SetDataInDesigner() {
      try {
        this.ActionGenerateLink();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("index.html/SetDataInDesigner =>", error);
      }
    }
    ActionGenerateLink() {
      try {
        const link = `${this.ObjectDesigner.InputValue01.value}${this.ObjectDesigner.InputValue02.value}${this.ObjectDesigner.InputValue03.value}`;
        const totalLink = `${this.DataStatic.KeyPhone}:${link}`;
        this.ObjectDesigner.LinkRedirect.innerText = `${this.DataStatic.KeyTitle} => ${totalLink}`;
        this.ObjectDesigner.LinkRedirect.setAttribute("href", totalLink);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("index.html/ActionGenerateLink =>", error);
      }
    }
  }
  const objApp = new App();
  objApp.Create();
})()
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="txtValue01">Value 01</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtValue01" value="(044)">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="txtValue02">Value 02</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtValue02" value="-">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="txtValue03">Value 03</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtValue03" value="955191560">
</div>
<div>
  <button id="btnGenerateLink">Generate Link</button>
  <a href="#" id="linkRedirect"></a>
</div>
```

Intenta vincular un evento con tus controles HTML, a partir de ahí recupera los valores y sumalos, luego de ello a tu control `<a>` setea el valor de dicha suma, te dejo un ejemplo.